# 3D Scene in 2D Project in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d

Okay, found another question that didn't have any answers and couldn't find anything else by Google Searching, YouTube searching, etc. So here comes the inevitable dumb question I ask every time I load up Unity (:

**How do I create/set up a 3D Scene in a 2D project?**
When creating my game project, I was anticipating using 2D to create the levels/UI. However, I've been looking into 3D lighting and other effects that would work better with 3D.

I need to either implement the lighting system crap into the Scene somehow or migrate the game into another 3D project and keep the 2D menu. I also would like to keep the animations/scripts (obviously) that I had before in the 2D scene that I'm trying to "convert".

And yes, I have tried creating 3D objects in the 2D scene, and yes, I have tried messing with the camera's rotation. I'm a lighting/shading/rendering noob when it comes to Game Dev, so please explain everything in detail... (:

Of course, as I'm sure you have found out already, I am not aware of any tutorials on this or other questions. If you have any pointers, I'm okay with that too. Thanks for any help in advance!

be nice I know im bad at Game dev ):

Comment: Really sorry if theres already another question like this, i haven't used stack in a while and am not rlly familiar with the policies and stuff lol, so far I haven't found anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fundamental difference between 2D and 3D scenes in Unity.

The 2D vs 3D project setting (which you can change at any time under Edit -> Project Settings) just configures some convenient defaults for you:

- In 2D mode, new image files found in your Assets folder will be imported as Sprite (2D and UI) type by default. In 3D mode, they'll be imported as Default type instead. You can change this for individual assets by clicking on them in the Project tab and modifying the type drop-down at the top of the Inspector.
- In 2D mode, new scenes will contain...

  - An orthographic camera, which clears to a solid colour before rendering.

  While in 3D mode, new scenes will contain...

  - A perspective camera, which clears to a default skybox set in the scene's lighting settings.
  - A directional light

  You can change the camera type by clicking on it in the hierarchy and changing its type/clear settings in the Inspector. You can add or delete directional lights as you like.
- In 2D mode, the Scene View will default to 2D (orthographic projection along the z+ axis), while in 3D mode, the Scene View will default to a perspective projection. You can toggle between these views by clicking the 2D button at the top of the Scene View tab.

That's it. So there's nothing to impede you from making 3D content when your project is configured for 2D or vice versa.

If you encounter any difficulty accomplishing a specific 3D task/effect, try editing your question to describe in detail what you're trying to achieve and where you're running into trouble.